# Cannot read binary file with bracket characters in C++

Tags: c++

I have function which reads a File & checks its contents.
The file contains some binary content along with non alphabet characters like `()`, `=`, `divided by symbol`, etc.
The function which does the reading is:

```
int FindMyWord(const char *fileName)
{
    ifstream myFile (fileName);
    if(!myFile)
        return false;
    string wordSearch = "MyWord";
    string line;
    int result = 0;
    while(getline(myFile, line))
    {
        if(line.find(wordSearch) != string::npos)
            result++;
    }
    //if(!myFile.eof() || !myFile)
    if(!myFile)
        printf("Problem Reading the File: %s\n", (const char *)fileName);

    myFile.close();
    return result;
}
```

I am having these 2 problems:

1. If a line contains binary characters then it is not reading the complete line, just reading the first word (atleast that's what I am observing by opening the file in VS2010).
2. When it encounters the character `(` for the beginning of a line the while loop is terminated & the `printf()` is printed.

If `string::getline()` cannot read such characters then what is the solution?
Thank You.

**UPDATE**: The Image of some of the binary data in the file:

[image]

Comment: You remove the brackets I added to that `if`...

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get you.

Comment: A text input stream should not fail on a bracket character.  If you actually need a binary stream, use `ifstream(filename, std::ios::binary)`.

Comment: Just so it's said, despite everything C and C++ do to try and ignore the difference, bytes aren't characters.  :P  If you're reading raw arbitrary bytes as text, expect weirdness.

Comment: @Pete your answer is correct, it works now.
Can you please add that as an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer?
Thanks

Comment: Please post a small example of the data.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews adding an image of the data in the question. I hope thats fine.

Comment: @CAD_coding done - cheers

Comment: Is you data *binary* or unicode?  Binary means the file contains unprintable characters like 0x05 or 0xEF.

Comment: Try opening it in Notepad++ or something ad see if it is unicode.  It looks more like you are tring to reverse engineer some binary format?

Comment: Probably solidworks by the look of it

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it looks the same in Notepad++, just some additional characters like NUL, SOH. So is it Unicode or Binary.

Comment: @Pete it is not SolidWorks, but let me tell you that it is our own file format. I am just working on another product of their's so dont know much about the file format specification. & I am definitely not doing reverse engineering! We just need to extract some data from that file which is concerned with our product!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text input stream should not fail on a bracket character.

If you actually need a binary stream, use ifstream(filename, std::ios::binary)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through the [std::getline docs at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). You should check the `failbit` on the stream if you have any odd behaviour.